SqlConnection from SqlClient not being recognized when trying to connect to SQL Server from a Unity Project through Microsoft Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to connect my Unity project with a SQL Server database using VS 2022, but when typing my code, I get the following error:

Error CS1069
The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\gerar\Unity\MSSQL_prueba\Assets\Scripts\GenerateLabels.cs    21  Active

Also, since I am new to .NET, I am not sure what type is being used (.NET / .NET Core), I am not diving into it as I am only trying to use it for Unity.
This is the code I am using:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient; // Here I use SqlClient
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEngine.UIElements.UxmlAttributeDescription;

public class GenerateLabels : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string UserName;

    function void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello world !!!");
        string connectionString =
           "Server=XX;" + 
           "Database=XX;" + 
           "User ID=XX;" + 
           "Password=XX;"; 
        IDbConnection dbcon;
        using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) // This line is where the error is displayed.
        {
            dbcon.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sql = "SELECT Name, UserPrincipalName FROM Users WHERE Id=1";
                dbcmd.CommandText = sql;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string FirstName = (string)reader["Name"];
                        string LastName = (string)reader["UserPrincipalName"];
                        UserName = "Name: " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
                        Debug.Log(UserName); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect position = new Rect(60, 20, 400, 60);
        GUI.Label(position, UserName);
    }
}

I researched the same issue online, and many solutions said to install the NuGet package System.Data.SqlClient by Microsoft. I had already installed it in its most recent stable version (4.8.6), but the error does not disappear, it's like if SqlConnection didn't exist inside it.

you sure you used the right one? and have the right settings in the build options?

@BugFinder, I am sure it is System.Data.SqlClient by Microsoft, version 4.8.6 (latest). Since the solution was created by Unity upon creating the script, I have pretty much not touched anything else apart from installing this package. I also checked the references and its reference does exist, but I am unable to find what the error is.

alarm bells are going of when you said install the package, what did you do? because the unity one is a DLL you need from one of the unity folders, and it has to be exactly the right folder or it doesnt work... its .. an art

@BugFinder, It was installed inside of Visual Studio trough the NuGet package manager. It was not installed through Uinity's interface.

that is probably why then

Aside... the legacy System.Data.SqlClient no longer receives new features. Consider using the modern and supported Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in new application development.
